# Начало цикла с новый данных

Tags: c#

Есть `3 цикла` от `000` до `999`, в коде прописано что если число, к примеру доходит до `193`, то он дальше не идет`(194,...200)` а начинается с `200`. Еще, если я прописал что `если число == "202"`, то дальше начинается уже с `300`(203 до 299 - не надо). Как это сделать, через `break;` пробовал, но немного не то что надо..

Comment: Забыть про `for`, использовать `do{}while` (и, возможно, ручное изменение счётчика).

Comment: Выкладывайте код, а в общем случае меняйте первый параметр `FOR` на нужный момент если это разные циклы, или меняйте последний параметр на нужную величину если это один и тот же цикл `FOR`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто добавляете `if` и делаете переход на нужный блок.

```
for( int  i= 0; i <= 999; i++ ) 
{
   if(i == 193)
   {
      i = 200;
   }
   else if(i == 202) 
   {
      i = 300;
   } 

   // ваш код
}
```

Comment: Возможно ли как нибудь сделать, чтобы не прописывать i=200; тупо дошел до 193 и какой нить командой перешел сразу на 200 ?

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать конструкцию switch..case внутри цикла для перемотки счетчика при достижении конкретных значений:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case (193) : i = 200; break;
        case (202) : i = 300; break;
    }

    /* DO SOMETHING ELSE */
}
```