# сброс цикла по алфавиту

Tags: c#

Уже спрашивал этот вопрос. но все-таки есть одна проблема...
[Начало цикла с новый данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765631/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

В ответе были прописан код, который **задавал сразу новое начало для цикла** а именно..

```
for( int  i= 0; i <= 999; i++ ) 
{
   if(i == 193)
   {
      i = 200;
   }
   else if(i == 202) 
   {
      i = 300;
   } 
}
```

Вот. Но суть в том чтобы, если работает не один цикл `i` а 3 подряд ну или 4, без разницы..
Пример:

```
string alfavit = "0123456789";
        for (int a = 0; a < alfavit.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < alfavit.Length; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < alfavit.Length; c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < alfavit.Length; d++)
                    {
                        string mystroka = alfavit[a].ToString() + alfavit[b].ToString() + alfavit[c].ToString() + alfavit[d].ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(mystroka);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Когда строка дошла до, допустим,`0012`, то вместо `b=0`, "автоматом" станет `b=1`, но как этого добится кодом? `0012` - набрал от руки, также когда дойдет до `0234` то вместо `a=0` должно будет быть `a=1`. **Без иф'ов!**
Исход на экране должен будет быть таким:

```
0012
0100
...
...
0234
0300
```

Comment: Я верно понял: вы хотите проверить какое то условие не используя условный оператор? В чем смысл этого?

Comment: @tym32167 смысл один - я хочу понять, как это сделать. Больше мне ничего не надо //(пока что)..это можно называть как угодно проверкой...еще как-нибудь."не используя условный оператор?" -да! Изменяя начальные `иф'ы` не прописывая в коде дополнительные опрераторы `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пойму, для чего вам 4 цикла. Попробуйте это:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9999;)
{       
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D4"));
    switch(i)
    {
        case 12:
            i = 100;
            break;
        case 193:
            i= 200;
            break;
        case 202:
            i=300;
            break;
        default:
            i++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Как видите, никаких `if` нет, инкремент счетчику присваиваем внутри цикла. Для вывода используем [форматирование целых чисел](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вывод:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
0011
0012
0100
0101
0102
0103
....
```

Если пробовать адаптировать ваш код, то получится следующее:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
            {
                int num = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;
                string mystroka = num.ToString("D4");
                Console.WriteLine(mystroka);

                switch (num)
                {
                    case 12:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 0;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    case 193:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 1;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    case 202:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 2;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    default:                            
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Еще вариант с "автоматическим" добавлением. Надеюсь, это то, что вы имеете ввиду

```
var valueToAdd = 0;
int num = 0;
for (int a = 0; num < 1000; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; num < 1000; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; num < 1000; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; num < 1000; d++)
            {
                num = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d + valueToAdd;
                string mystroka = num.ToString("D4");
                Console.WriteLine(mystroka);

                switch (num)
                {
                    case 12:
                        valueToAdd = 87;
                        break;
                    case 193:
                        valueToAdd = 93;
                        break;
                    case 202:
                        valueToAdd = 190;
                        break;
                    default:                            
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Всегда нравилась в вопросах формулировка "без if-ов", можно подумать в циклах или switch их нет, просто другая форма записи =)

Comment: @rdorn это зависит от того, что авто вопроса имеет ввиду. Не использовать if в своем коде - это одно дело. Не использовать условные переходы совсем - совсем другое. [Как пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636458/how-to-create-a-matrix-without-a-loop/38636607#38636607) подобного вопроса, только про циклы.

Comment: @tym32167 если все таки брать и модифицировать циклы начальные то как автоматизировать `a,b,c` ? `i = 100;i=200;i=300;` вот эти цифры `1,2,3` должны менятся сами, но не прописывав их коде, вот чего хочу добится

Comment: То есть когда  дошло до 193..то вместо `b=0, "автоматом" станет b=1`, когда дошел до `193` то `b=2, "автоматом" станет b=3`...`b` из цикла менятся дальше должно `само`

Comment: @Rolly Я не понимаю, что значит `само`? Само в программе ничего не происходит, все, что происходит, задано программистом. Но я обновил ответ - добавил ваш код, только поправил его немного.

Comment: @tym32167 объясняю что значит `само` :-) идет цикл от и до, как у меня от 0 до `.Length`, вот, когда, к примеру, 0 то идет 0(const) 12,13,14,...099, потом 0(const) меняется на 1(и цикл с int b=0 выводит на экран значения, которые соответствуют тому, что как будто там не int b=0 a int b=1;, т.к. 100,101,...199,когда идет 2XX(X=>числа от 00 до 99) то int b не будет уже 1 а уже 2 ну итд..так вот нужно автоматизировать замену 1 на 2, 2 на 3...ну итд..теперь луше ?

Comment: @Rolly если честно, то вы меня только ещё больше запутали :)

Comment: @Rolly переделал последний пример на switch-case

Comment: @Rolly добавил ещё вариант. Смотрите, изучайте.

Comment: @tym32167 такое доп. вопрос: с switch кейсами прекрасно работает..`switch (num)
                {
                    case 12:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 0;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;` как быть если я хочу сразу 7 значений в case 1: добавить  в кейсе 12; a=0, а как будет если a=0 далее a=2,a=3 ? Чтобы не писать по 7 кейсов..

Comment: @Rolly так и пишите `case 1: case2: case3:` вместо простого `case 1:`

Comment: @tym32167 я имею ввиду одновременно несколько значений `a=0` и `a=1` в `case 1:` можно написать типа `case1:a=1`, `case2:a=2`,`case3:a=3`, а если нужно так: `case1:a=1` и потом в этом же `кейсе 1 будет a=2,a=3...`

Comment: @Rolly Не понял, что вы хотите сделать. Несколько раз переменную в одном кейсе поменять? Это смысла не имеет

Comment: @tym32167 вы в своем примере написали пару кейсов и в каждом прописали `b=0;b=1,b=2` почему низя, чтобы комп брал подряд 0,1,2 в **одном кейсе** 1,2,3 типа `case 1:b=0&&b=1&&b=2`...примерно так, но я тестил - не пашет такой код.... а надо бы..((

Comment: @Rolly Вам надо переосмыслить логику работы того, что вы хотите написать, так как `1:b=0&&b=1&&b=2` - бессмыслица

Comment: @tym32167 но ведь можно же как-то записать иначе сразу пару значений b в одном кейсе ? Или прописать что-то типа от и до, как-то сократить что ли..не писать же 15 кейсов и в каждом 0,1,2,3,4,5....а кейс один раз и в нем что-то типа цикла или еще как-нибудь.....хз

Comment: @Rolly b - это переменная. Она хранит только одно значение. Если вы напишете `b=1;b=2;b=3;` то это будет тоже самое, что просто `b=3;`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72981/discussion-between-rolly-and-tym32167).

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, пусть будет так, но как тогда написать чтобы подряд шло, если цикл не подходит, кейсы стругать не нужно! Ну или что еще можно чтобы комп выполнял что это будет НЕ тоже самое, что просто b=3;как сократить, но чтобы выполнялся код от 1 до 7, в одной кейсе ?? `b` "шло" как по циклу от 1 до 7 ?

Comment: @tym32167 как сделать цикл в кейсе ?

Comment: @Rolly поглядите на ваш изначальный вопрос и что вы говорите сейчас - по моему вы либо новые требования добавляете, либо новый вопрос задаёте. Я вам предлагаю собраться с мыслями, сформулировать ваш вопрос как то попонятней, и задать его отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @tym32167 задал новый вопрос! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783766/%d0%a6%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-switch-case

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
IEnumerable<int> Range(int from, int to) => Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1);
IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    foreach (var seq in sequences)
        foreach (var item in seq)
            yield return item;
}

var ranges = new[]
{
    Range(0, 12),
    Range(100, 193),
    Range(200, 202),
    Range(300, 999)
};

foreach (var i in Concat(ranges))
    Console.WriteLine($"{i:D4}");
```

---

Заметьте, что функцию `Concat` можно записать более простым, но, возможно, менее понятным для новичков способом:

```
IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ll) => ll.SelectMany(l => l);
```

---

В C# 7.3 появится [Range](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23205), и можно будет писать просто

```
var ranges = new[] { 0..12,  100..193, 200..202, 300..999 };
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72683/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со словарём переходов:

```
var jumps = new Dictionary<int, int> { [12]=100, [194]=200, [203]=300 };
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i = jumps.TryGetValue(i, out var j) ? j : i + 1)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i:D4}");
```

или, без введения переменной `j`:

```
var jumps = new Dictionary<int, int> { [12]=100, [194]=200, [203]=300 };
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i = jumps.ContainsKey(i) ? jumps[i] : i + 1)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i:D4}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = new Range { 
    {1, 2}, 
    {5, 9}, 
};

foreach(var i in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i:D4}");
```

Результат вызова

```
0001
0002
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
```

Простая реализация.

```
public class Range : List<int>
{
    public void Add(int from, int to)
    {
        AddRange(Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1));
    }
}
```

Вторая версия. Улучшено потребление памяти.

```
public class Range : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private List<IEnumerable<int>> intervals = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();

    public Range Add(int from, int to)
    {
        intervals.Add(Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1));
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(var interval in intervals)
            foreach(var i in interval)
                yield return i;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Код можно вызывать и цепочкой

```
var numbers = new Range()
    .Add(1, 2)
    .Add(5, 9);

//...
```

Comment: Здесь, в отличие от ответа @VladD, коллекция создается и заполняется, что уже ведет к значительному расходу памяти

Comment: @АндрейNOP Добавил улучшенную версию. Но суть вызывающего кода осталась простой. Переиспользовать легче. Можно воткнуть в библиотеку :)

Comment: Я бы назвал ваш класс не `Range`, а хотя бы `Ranges`, т. к. их там много.

Comment: @VladD Да, у меня была такая идея... но оставим уже как есть ;)