# Цикл(ы) в switch case

Tags: c#

```
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
            {
                int num = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;
                string mystroka = num.ToString("D4");
                Console.WriteLine(mystroka);

                switch (num)
                {
                    case 12:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 0;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    case 193:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 1;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    case 202:
                        a = 0;
                        b = 2;
                        c = 9;
                        d = 9;
                        break;
                    default:                            
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

как переделать эту часть, чтобы было бы вот так: 
switch (num)

```
    {
                        case 12:
                            a = 0;
                            b = 0&&b=1&&b=2; //остальное аналогично
                            c = 9;
                            d = 9;
                            break;
                        default:                            
                            break;
                    }
```

Цикл прописать как-то для `b`, чтобы не писать энтое кол-ство кейсов..

Comment: `b = 0&&b=1&&b=2;` что это значит? Почему вы продолжаете использовать это решение вместо кучи других предложенных в прошлом вопросе?

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему ? Потому-что не знаю, как еще можно записать, кроме как такую запись сделать.У вас есть другие варианты?

Comment: Какое целевое назначение этого кода? Выглядит бессмысленно

Comment: @yolosora Цикл прописать как-то для b, чтобы не писать энтое кол-ство кейсов..

Comment: @Rolly вы не правильно поняли мой вопрос, что вы хотите чтобы этот блок кода делал? Выглядит так как будто вы в корне неправильно подошли к решению

Comment: Например, используйте не 4 цикла, а один и словарь переходов, как я вам уже предлагал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779951/218063), а еще лучше возьмите ответ @VladD. Я не понимаю, почему из всех предложенных вам ответов вы продолжаете использовать самый плохой.

Comment: @yolosora возможно  вы правы..`b` идет от 0 до 10(цикл такой), я хочу чтобы когда циклы доходят до числа 0012 то потом был бы `0123` потом `0247`, `0587`. Как вы видите посл. 2 знака обычный цикл, когда посл. 2 числа доходят до опред. варианта то есть `23`,`47`,`87` не важно, может быть любые варианты, то `b` идет по строке дальше, т.н. "сброс по алфавиту"

Comment: Меня интересует чтобы "автоматом" `b` менялся дальше знак за знаком, через кейсы, поэтому и назвал цикл(ы) в кейсе а не в кейсах

Comment: вы очень сильно усложняете, используйте один цикл от 0 до 10000 вместо того чтобы каждый раз собирать число вручную, заведите например `Dictionary<int,int>` на итерациях проверяйте значение на наличие в ключах словаря, если такой ключ есть - перещелкивайте на значение по ключу

Comment: @yolosora извините, какого ключа ? Не понял..(

Comment: @Rolly почитайте про коллекцию `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` она хранит пары в формате ключ-значение

Comment: @Rolly И все-таки, что должна делать ваша запись? `b = 0&&b=1&&b=2;`

Comment: не понимаю Ваш эльфийский, но думаю Вы могли бы написать так `bool itIsFutility = Convert.ToBoolean(b=0) && Convert.ToBoolean(b=1) && Convert.ToBoolean(b = 2);`, тогда оно хотя бы скомпилиться... зачем-то  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, я начинаю понимать, что вам нужно. НО

1. Вы определенно все больше и больше запутываете код. Так никто не делает. Если интерес чисто академический, то ок. Если практический - то мой пример ниже будет только вреден.
2. Если вам нужна *короткая* форма записи, то смотрите ответы в вашем предыдущем вопросе. Ниже не короткая форма.

Итак, я понял так, что вы не хотите в каждом кейсе дублировать работу. Вы можете сделать так:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
            {
                int num = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;
                string mystroka = num.ToString("D4");
                Console.WriteLine(mystroka);

                bool matched = false;
                switch (num)
                {
                    case 12:                            
                        b = 0;                          
                        matched = true;
                        break;
                    case 193:                           
                        b = 1;
                        matched = true;                         
                        break;
                    case 202:                           
                        b = 2;
                        matched = true;                                                     
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (matched)
                {
                    a = 0;                      
                    c = 9;
                    d = 9;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь в кейсах вы меняете только b и флаг. Кейсы стали чуть короче, вся программа выросла на 2 строчки.

Comment: Вангую, ТС хочет сделать цикл по цифрам вместо цикла по числу (недавно был похожий вопрос). (И не умеет выводить ведущие нули без этого.)

Comment: @VladD я уже [предлагал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779906/179763) цикл по числу, да и сложно понять, что автору конкретно надо. Мне кажется, сам автор не уверен, что ему надо.

Comment: Ах, это тот же автор! Получается, он создаёт сам себе сложности, и потом просит нас их героически преодолеть. Похоже на [XY Problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105).

Comment: @VladD да, я потому ему и написал `Вы определенно все больше и больше запутываете код. Так никто не делает.` в самом начал своего ответа

Comment: Мне вообще кажется (по стилю изложения и коду), что это пользователь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216027/komra23 который аж с позапрошлого года, меняя ники и задавая схожие вопросы, ваяет некий хитромудрый проект с непоследовательным перебором чисел в текстовых файлах :)

Comment: @tym32167 да, теперь то то надо! :)

Comment: @VladD мне tym сказал чтобы я сделал новый вопрос, я так и сделал, не не давно, а новый вопрос! "Ах, это тот же автор! Получается, он создаёт сам себе сложности, и потом просит нас их героически преодолеть" - нет, у меня есть вопрос, пытаюсь сам его решить, ессли не выходит спрашиваю тут

Comment: @Rolly Подтверждаю, я не понял, что автор хотел получить и [посоветовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779903/%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/779906#comment1230139_779906) задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @playerone коды везде ==, стил, на мой взгляд везде одинаковый...менять ники, как вы выразались, а зачем их менять, не совсем понимаю..есть ник один, один юзер, другой ник - другой юзер..схожие вопросов я могу найти в сети много, от разных юзеров..и что у одного 1000 репа у другого 102 , == юзеры ??, проект? , какой проект? Не пишу проекты..тхт файлы - мне не нужны

Comment: @tym32167 ну да! Все верно